# how to update all rows except first?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this sql query :

```
update CCUSTOMERINFO set VALIDTO=sysdate where (
select * from (
select row_number() over (order by created desc) rn, customer_id, CCUSTOMERINFO.VALIDTO
from CCUSTOMERINFO
where customer_id=100309772  order by created DESC) where rn > 1);
```

But it say it have some mistake.

This query returns all i want to update :

```
 select * from (
    select row_number() over (order by created desc) rn, customer_id, CCUSTOMERINFO.VALIDTO
    from CCUSTOMERINFO
    where customer_id=100309772  order by created DESC) where rn > 1)
```

Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use it like the below

```
  update CCUSTOMERINFO set VALIDTO=sysdate where rowid in (
  select row_id from (
  select row_number() over (order by created desc) rn, customer_id, rowid row_id,
  CCUSTOMERINFO.VALIDTO
  from CCUSTOMERINFO
  where customer_id=100309772  order by created DESC) where rn > 1);
```

Comment: I had to use AS <some alias> in order to work this